# Extract portion of image on touch

Tags: ios, swift

When a user clicks on the screen I save an image as a `UIImage`. Also the users touch coordinates are saved.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first

    if let p = touch?.location(in: view) { }
}
```

Now, the problem I have is I tried to place the x and y that I obtained from the touch, and crop a part from the image that I saved initially. However, a different section gets cropped. How can I solve this ?

I also found [this post that says there are issues converting touch points on to a Image.](http://www.b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/uiimageview-transforming-touch-coordinates-to-pixel-coordinates/)

Comment: You'll have to provide a bit more information, code, and so on. Right now it's difficult to understand what you want to do and what is the issue with it.

Comment: Is the image actually the same size in pixels as the view is in points? If that's not the case, you need to take into the ratio between the two...

Comment: I didn't down-vote for the record. But really, you haven't yet provided enough code to explain the issue. It could be related to several things - layout, scaling, how you are cropping - and I'm just naming the first thing that come to mind. Can you provide more to help us duplicate the issue?

Comment: @jcaron how can I take a ratio. I don't think it has the same pixels

Comment: Uh, `width_of_picture * x / width_of_view`? And the same for y/height. Of course it presumes the image covers the whole of the view, which may not be the case either, and then the calculation is a bit more complex.

Comment: What is your view hierarchy ?, Where the image placed ? ,are you using scrollview? , is image is rotated ? ,is image is zoomed ?  it matters here, as you need to convert touch point to relative image point,

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer which has same functionality , as question is very unclear still might be helpful

Here is a View Hierarchy

```
--> ScrollView 
 --> ViewBase (View might be zoomed and rotated)
   --> TargetImageView (Rect to be cropped (Touch point here for you))
```

And here is how to do it

```
CGPoint locationInImageView =  [self.viewBase convertPoint:self.targetImageview.center toView:self.view]; // received from touch
locationInImageView =  [self.view convertPoint:locationInImageView toView:self.imgVPhoto];


UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, 0);

[self.imgVPhoto.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *img1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Here  2 is image scale  and zoomScale is what it is zoomed :)

CGFloat width = self.targetImageview.frame.size.width * self.zoomScale / 2 ;
CGFloat height = self.targetImageview.frame.size.height * self.zoomScale  / 2;

CGFloat xPos = (locationInImageView.x  * 2)  - width / 2;
CGFloat yPos = (locationInImageView.y * 2) - height / 2;

CGRect rect1 = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, width, height);

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([img1 CGImage], rect1);

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:img1.scale orientation:img1.imageOrientation];
// Check image here
```

Hope it is helpful to you